# Random item from array with no repeat using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get random items from an array with no repeat?

I have an array of elements like

```
var a = ["Mango", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Grapes", "Berry", "Peach"]
```

I want to get 3 random items from array `a`

```
var random = ["Banana", "Berry", "Peach"]
```

Comment: There are many questions like this here, have you tried searching?

Comment: What code have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Shuffle the array, then slice the result.

Comment: Already answered here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963358/javascript-how-to-make-a-random-array-with-no-repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963358/javascript-how-to-make-a-random-array-with-no-repeats)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning function value from array using random selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716631/returning-function-value-from-array-using-random-selection)

Comment: I have a working solution now if you are stilll interested

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = ["Mango","Orange","Banana","Apple","Grapes","Berry","Peach"];

function searchRandom(count, arr){
  let answer = [], counter = 0;
 
  while(counter < count){
    let rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    if(!answer.some(an => an === rand)){
      answer.push(rand);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  
  return answer;
}

console.log(searchRandom(3,a))
```

Making it flexible to support any `count` you want and ensured uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ["Mango","Orange","Banana","Apple","Grapes","Berry","Peach"]
var res = a.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
console.log(res.slice(a,3))
```

Comment: Careful, `.sort` sorts the array _in place_, modifying the original one. You should make a copy and sort that one if you don't want any side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var a = ["Mango","Orange","Banana","Apple","Grapes","Berry","Peach"]
b = _.shuffle(a).slice(0,5);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without any duplicates:

```js
const a = ["Mango","Orange","Banana","Apple","Grapes","Berry","Peach"]
const b = a.slice()
const newArr = [];

for(let i= 0; i<3; i++){
 let arr = b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)];
  
 let index = b.indexOf(arr);
  
  b.splice(index, 1 );
  
  newArr.push(arr)
  
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to improve the Willem van der Veen's answer because his code might return undefined. It stems from the fact that the arrayClone takes out the random item but random number still in the range of the previous index length. Hence, the solution is we have to decrease the arrayClone's length too:

```js
    const array = [0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9]

    const arrayClone = array.slice()

    let arrayLength = array.length

    let newArray = []

    for (  let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let arr = arrayClone[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)]

        arrayLength--

        let index = arrayClone.indexOf(arr)

        arrayClone.splice(index, 1)

        newArray.push(arr)
     }


      console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Good  answer, and we can improve little bit like this;
const array = [0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9]
    const arrayClone = array.slice();
    let arrayLength = array.length;
    let newArray = [];
    for (  let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrayLength--));
  newArray.push(arrayClone.splice(random, 1)[0]); //arrayClone.splice(random, 1) returns removed items, here we removed one item so we can simply get 0 element of removed item
     }
     console.log(newArray);